# How to download dependency jars using sbt?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, spark-csv

`Spark-csv 2.10` builds successfully using `sbt` but while starting the scala service every time need to give the --packages tag. Is there any other way to include packages instead of this tag?

```
spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0
```

Thanks

Comment: You can create an uber JAR using [`sbt-assembly`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) with the dependency pre-included inside.

Comment: Created dependency jar using `sbt-assembly`, `spark-csv-assembly-1.4.0.jar` only created not other jar files created for spark-csv execution.
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.csv. Please find packages at http://spark-packages.org`